# Apply result of IF statement on multiple cells

Tags: excel, if-statement

I want to apply the result of an IF statement on multiple cells, so for example A2, A2 and A3 are equal to 1, 2 or 3.

When A2 is equal to 1 I want to get B2,B3,B4 = 1,0,0

When A3 is equal to 2 to get B5,B6,B7 = 0,1,0

And when A4 is equal to 3 to get B8,B9,B10 = 0,0,1

Is this possible?

Comment: You could write a formula like IF(A2=1,1) in B2 and a similar formula in the other 8 cells. But you'd also need to specify what should happen if A2<>1 (in this case, it would show FALSE in B2). I can also see a way of writing a more general formula that you could copy from B2 to B3:B10 which is probably better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing about Excel: you can't write a formula that changes the contents of another cell. A formula only gives a result in the current cell. That result may well be based on the contents of several other cells, and the result in the current cell may be used by several other cells.

So here are two possible answers:

(1) In B2, write

```
=If(A2=1,1,"")
```

In B3, write

```
=If(A2=1,0,"")
```

and keep going for the other 7 cells B4:B10.

(2) If you wanted a single formula that would do roughly what you describe, it would be quite complicated but do-able.

In B2, write

```
=IF(INDEX(A$2:A$4,(ROW()+1)/3)=INT((ROW()+1)/3),IF(MOD(ROW()+1,3)+1=INDEX(A$2:A$4,(ROW()+1)/3),1,0),"")
```

and pull or copy this down through cells B3:B10.

Then use Formulas | Evaluate Formula to see what it does.

**EDIT**

If A2, A3 etc can be 1, 2 or 3 then the formula would be simpler

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()+1,3)+1=INDEX(A$2:A$4,(ROW()+1)/3),1,0)
```

- you're just seeing if the remainder on dividing the row in column B by 3 (+1) is equal to the corresponding value (1, 2 or 3) in A2, A3 etc.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it only seems to work when I have 1,2,3 for A2,A3,A4 in this exact order. However, in my problem each cell in A has a number which is either 1,2 or 3 chosen at 'random', so it can be 3,2,1 as well. I also don't just have 3 cells in A, I have 1500. I got the desired column by means of a small program in Python, but I would also like to know how to get the same result in Excel.

Comment: In this kind of situation it's helpful to expand the question by showing some sample data and results so we can get a clearer picture of what's needed. But anyway, would I be right in thinking that if A2 was equal to 2, you would want B2,B3,B4 to be 0,1,0 and if it was 3, you would want B2,B3,B4 to be 0,0,1? I will add to my answer.